# Change color of an individual Calendar Event in Google Calendar using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to change the color of some individual calendar events that start with the word "Klausur". There seems to be a problem with the setColor() method. But I cant figure out why. If I call the method on the entire calendar it dose work but on individual events it dose not.

```
function changeKlausurColor() {
    var now = new Date();
    var start = new Date(now.getTime() - (604800 * 1000 * 52));
    var end = new Date(now.getTime() + (604800 * 1000 * 52));
    var srcCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CalendarID");
    var events = srcCal.getEvents(start, end);
    for (var i in events) {
        if (events[i].getTitle().indexOf("Klausur") == 0) {
            var color = events[i].setColor("#0D7813");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the event color from [Enum EventColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color). When this is reflected to your script, please modify as follows.

#### From :

```
var color = events[i].setColor("#0D7813");
```

#### To :

```
var color = events[i].setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.GREEN);
```

#### References :

- [setColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setColor(String))
- [Enum EventColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color)

Comment: Is there a way to set custom colors? Why can we only use the Enum EventColors?

Comment: @sadiela I would like to support you. About your 2 questions, I would like to propose to ask them as new questions. By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?